# how to access the first row of the dataframe after using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and pandas and need help with the following.
I have some data in a dataframe on which I am using `groupby` function. After using the `groupby` function I want to access the first row of each group and copy the same to a different `dataframe`.
For eg.

```
grouped = com.groupby(['Month'])
```

Using this will give me groups created month-wise. I just want to extract the first number from all the 12 groups and copy the same row details to another `dataframe`.

Comment: `com.groupby(['Month']).head(1)`.

Comment: buy I also need to copy the same to another dataframe.